# Canadian permanent resident visiting Japan

Tags: visas, canada, japan, afghan-citizens

I am a Canadian permanent resident and living in Canada. I am originally from Afghanistan and would like to visit my girlfriend in Japan. I know Canadian passport holder can simply enter into Japan without a visa and as a permanent resident of Canada can I also enter Japan without a visa for 30 days?

Comment: I live in Vancouver

Comment: Permanent Residence status is not citizenship and the majority of visa / entry rules are based on citizenship.

Comment: One of the extremely few exceptions to the rule @Tom mentions is the Schengen transit visa: holders of a valid residence permit issued by Andorra, Canada, Japan, San Marino or the United States of America do not need a Schengen transit visa. Do note this is only the *transit* visa, the short stay visa does not have such an exception.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I am afraid NO, as an Afghan national and Canadian permanent resident you need a proper visitor's visa. Answer is from official [Consulate-General of Japan in Vancouver](http://www.vancouver.ca.emb-japan.go.jp/en/visa/visit_faq.htm#visafaq3):

> **I am a permanent resident of Canada. Do I need a tourist visa?**
>
> It depends on your nationality or the passport you hold. If you hold
>   a passport of a country with a reciprocal visa exemption arrangement
>   with Japan, you do not need a visa to enter Japan as a tourist.
>   Otherwise, you need one. More on Temporary Visitor's Visas.

Unfortunately Afghanistan is not listed in those countries who are listed as a visa exempted country. Source: [Ministry of Foreign Affairs Japan](http://www.mofa.go.jp/j_info/visit/visa/short/novisa.html). Therefore as an Canadian permenant resident and Afghan national you will need a proper Japan temporary visitor's visa.

Moreover, details regarding temporary visitors visa can be obtained from the following website:

Temporary Visitor's Visa  [Consulate-General of Japan in Vancouver](http://www.vancouver.ca.emb-japan.go.jp/en/visa/temporary.htm).